# JSLint error - Expected '/' and instead saw ''

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

When validating my sourcecode in JSLint, I received the following error, despite everything working at run time:

```
Expected '/' and instead saw ''.
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

code snippet of sourcecode:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function() {
    ...
} 

</script>
```

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I guess JSLint is doesn't like linting HTML?

Comment: Only older versions of JSLint would lint inline HTML. Can you tell us what tool you're using to lint? And are you sure this is where it sees an error? What error are you getting exactly, and how does it line up with your full code? That said, trying putting some spaces into `window.onload = function () {` exactly like that, then add a `;` after your trailing `}` and see what happens -- I think that age of JSLint would complain about your current construction.

Comment: Seeing the same issue when I lint a react js file.

Answer (score 1):

JSLint is not meant for inline Javascript linting. Instead move your JS code to an external file and lint that file.